# Keep last minute video with AVCaptureVideoDataOutput

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I am grabbing frames this way with swift 3 and AVCaptureSession.

What i want to do is to store frames in memory. Easy ? I just have to store my pixel buffer in memory, or write it to a document file...

But i want to store about one minute of frames and then delete older frames to replace by new ones. When the user will hit a button, i want to keep in memory the last minute of frames. I have tried to write a double chained-list, but i do not think it is a good thing for performance. Is there a best way to do that, with AVFoundation tools ?

Thanks

```
        let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        videoOutput.videoSettings =  [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
        videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "my queue"))
        if session.canAddOutput(videoOutput)
        {
            session.addOutput(videoOutput)
        }

       // AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate
      func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!)
     {
         NSLog("frame")
         let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!
     }
```

Comment: 1 minute of 1080p RGBA frames at 30fps is 60*30*1920*1080*4 bytes, or about 14GB - that's not going to easily fit into memory.

Comment: so let's say 15 seconds instead of 1 minute

Comment: about 900MB of data. still too big! maybe lower resolution and switch to yuv?

Comment: Oops, I mean 3.5GB